# Working with PHP variables between templates

Tags: php

What is the best way to "send" a PHP variable between templates? I have an array `$myArray` that I create in my `index.html` template. Then I have a template which goes to fetch data from an external API, and store the items in `$myArray`. And then I've turned on caching for this template, so I won't have to churn through the API request on every load. Then back at the `index.html` I want to output stuff from `$myArray`.

Basically it would look something like this:

```
//index.html:
<?php global $myArray; ?>
{embed="include/api"}
<?php
foreach ($myArray as $m) {
    //output
} ?>

//api.html:
global $myArray;
$myArray = getAPIdata(); //getAPIdata just fetches stuff and returns the array
```

Now, this doesn't work of course. But I don't know why. And I don't have any other ideas on how to accomplish this. Especially since I want caching on my `api.html` template.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever enable php in a template. Aside from being a security risk it's also just ugly and hard to maintain.

Take some time to learn how to build your functionality as an add-on. Plugins are the simplest type of add-on to get started with: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html

In terms of the specifics of saving data across page loads, take a look at the [session class](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html)